# send messages to content script from background script when using geckoview

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, geckoview

I use geckoview to replace android builtin webview.
I want to send messages from background script to content script to update the content of the web page, but I don't know how.
Can anyone provide an example to do that?

Many thanks.

I want to use geckoview to replace webview to show custom contents like webview.loadDataWithBaseURL() does.